# Is 'and' essential in a colon list?

Tags: punctuation, colons, list-order

I would like to know if an 'and' is always necessary before the last item in a colon list.

Is the following correct, or should I place an 'and' before 'grapes'?

> The basket contained a variety of fruits: bananas, apples, oranges,
> grapes.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [colon before a list of questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/344519/colon-before-a-list-of-questions) (where 'and' is inappropriate).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Omitting "and" in a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15970/omitting-and-in-a-sentence) "... not only is it [omitting an expected 'and', before the last term in a list, say] a valid device, but it has a name."

Answer (score 3):

The deceptively simple answer is that *and* is customary before the last item in a comma-delimited list

> (in a sentence, at least; bulleted lists on slides don't fall under grammatical rules).

This means that leaving it out draws attention to the sentence.
And that's exactly what the author intends to do -- draw attention to the sentence.

The result of leaving the *and* out, in speech, is to end the sentence without a full-stop intonation dip. That leaves the perception that something is still left to come, and we strain to hear it -- or at least our instincts do, and our parsing habits are guided by them. The result is a peculiar form of emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

You should put "and" before the final item in the list. According to [ThePunctuationGuide.com](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/colon.html),

> The colon is used to introduce a list of items.
>
> *Example*
>
> The bookstore specializes in three subjects: art, architecture, **and** graphic design.
>
> Do not, however, use a colon when the listed items are incorporated into the flow of the sentence.
>
> *Correct*
>
> The bookstore specializes in art, architecture, and graphic design.
>
> *Incorrect*
>
> The bookstore specializes in: art, architecture, and graphic design.

Comment: Omission is unusual, but not in itself ungrammatical. See the duplicate thread, and the other link.